# Clickable links API in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an API to create clickable links? VS Code highlights URLs and allows to ctrl-click them, and the typescript integration allows to ctrl-click file path on imports, so the functionality is there.

The [activation reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events) didn't mention anything about text manipulation / highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different things you mix in your question:

1. **Link detection** This is a built in mechanism that identifies links in any text file. It underlines links and provides the CTRL+Click command to open that link inside your browser.
2. **[Definition provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DefinitionProvider)** Usually implemented by an external language server using the [Language Server Protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol). When you perform CTRL+Click on an import statement in a TypeScript file then these things will happen in background

   - VSCode will look up a definition provider for the current language (in this case it's TypeScript)
   - VSCode will call `provideDefinition` on the definition provider object having the clicked cursor position as argument
   - The definition provider has got the knowledge about the programming language. So it will be able to parse the source code and to find out where the clicked identifier is defined. It will return the corresponding file location.
   - VSCode jumps to that file location

This is a simplified example. In fact all this will happen as soon as you hold CTRL and hover over an identifer. When a definition provider responds with a valid location the identifer will be displayed underlined.

Checkout the [extension samples](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/samples) to learn how to create your own definition provider.

Comment: Which sample uses `DefinitionProvider`?  I searched the repo and can't find any reference to that or `provideDefinition` in the samples repo.